# Error when running an application based on SQL Server in a Docker container

Tags: .net, sql-server, docker, docker-compose, docker-container

I am new to docker and I encountered the following problem: I want to run an app (that internally uses sql server) in a container, but I get the following error:

> Could not run migrations. Reason: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server: Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

I tried to install sql server on my laptop and enable tcp just in case, but as far as I know, when running the app in a container, I shoulden't install the dependencies on my laptop.

I mention that for running the app inside docker I use the following commands:

```
docker build -t identity_web_api .

docker-compose up
```

The Docker compose file:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web_api:
    image: identity_web_api
    container_name: identity_web_api
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
  sql:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest"
    container_name: identity_sql_server
    ports: # not actually needed, because the two services are on the same network
      - "1433:1433" 
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=y
      - SA_PASSWORD=SomePass!234
```

Comment: You say that the app is internally using SQL Server, so where exactly is that SQL Server instance installed? Is it another Docker container using the image based on `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server`? Is it in the same Docker composition, another one, or a standalone container? What does your `docker-compose.yml` file look like? What does your app's connection string look like?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I was not sure if I need SQL Server installed on my machine as well, so I installed it just in case. As for the docker composition file, I updated my question to include it as well. It uses the Microsoft image and they seem to be on the same container.

Comment: Being separate services they are also separate containers. The container for `web_api` service is named `identity_web_api` in (Docker's) DNS, the one for `sql` is `identity_sql_server`. The connection string in your web app should use the Docker DNS name of the SQL container, so along the lines of `Server=tcp:identity_sql_server,1433;...rest of params here...`. You will need to do more work to get the SQL container configured as well, since the default image only has the `master`, `model`, `msdb` and `tempdb` databases - you need to create your user database(s) along with logins and users.